# Задачи на использование массивов и функций

Tags: массивы, pascal, циклы, freepascal

Вот пытался сделать несколько заданий из последней лабораторной (не свой вариант), но что-то ничего не выходит 
Прошу сообщетво помочь мне с решением и пояснить где же оишибки!
Вот первая задача:
После первого четного элемента вставить 0.
Пример: из массива А[5]: 1 6 8 3 4 должен получиться массив А[6]: 1 6 0 8 3 4.
Вот код:

```
    program lab_finyak_5_1;

const
  n = 7;

type
  mymas = array[1..n] of integer;


function el_mas(var x: mymas): integer;
var
  i,lol: integer;
begin
  for i:= 1 to n do
   begin
     x[i] := random(30);
   end;

   for i:= 1 to n do
    begin
     if (x[i] div 2 = 0) then
      begin
        lol := i;
      end;
     { break; }
    end;

   el_mas:= lol;
end;


var
  a: mymas; 
  i,m_lol: integer;


BEGIN
randomize;

m_lol := el_mas(a);
for i := 1 to n do
 begin
  write(a[i], ' ');
 end;

writeln;
writeln(m_lol);
writeln;

 for i := 1 to n do
  begin
  if (i = m_lol) then
   begin
    write(a[i],' ', '0', ' ');
   end
  else
   begin
    write(a[i], ' ');
   end;  
  end;

readln;
END.
```

Здесь у меня постоянно выдает ноль:

```
26 7 24 2 18 11 22 
0
26 7 24 2 18 11 22
```

А вот вторая задача:
После последнего кратного четырем элемента вставить 0.
Пример: из массива А[5]: 1 3 8 3 4должсн получиться массив А[6]: 1 3 8 3 4 0.
Вот код:

```
program lab_sashka_g_5_1;

function m_mas(var x:array of integer):integer;
var
 i,el: integer;
  begin
    for i:= 0 to high(x) do
     begin
       x[i] := random(20);
       if (x[i] div 4 = 0) then
        begin
          el := i;
        end;
     end;  
    m_mas := el;
  end;

var
  a:array[1..6] of integer;
  i,lol: integer;

BEGIN
randomize;
 lol := m_mas(a);

 for i := 1 to 6 do
  begin
    write(a[i], ' ');
  end;

writeln;
write(lol);
writeln;

 for i := 1 to 6 do
  begin
    if (i = lol) then
     begin
       write(a[i], ' ', '0', ' ');
     end
    else
     begin
       write(a[i], ' ');
     end;
  end; 

END.
```

Здесь я получаю какую-то фигню на выходе:

```
12 19 0 11 13 6 
2
12 19 0 0 11 13 6
```

По коду выходит, что у меня должно после первого четного эл-ма в массиве выводить ноль, но почему-то у него вышло, что 19 - четное (19 div 2 = 0)...
Помогите.

Comment: "Здесь у меня постоянно выжает ноль((" - где именно? покажите полностью, что выводит.

Comment: "Здесь я получаю какую-то фигню на выходе" - какую именно фигню?

Comment: написал, что выводит

Comment: используйте `mod 2 = 0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оператор div возвращает частное при делении с остатком, mod -  сам остаток. `if (x[i] div 2 = 0)` не проверяет чётность числа, а то является ли частное нулём. На вашем вводе таких числе нет, поэтому значение переменной lol не изменяется: инициализируется оно нулём, в других языках инициализация может быть другой... Поиск в цикле  `for i := 1 to n do`, естественно, найти позицию 0 не может: условие `i = m_lol` всегда ложно.

Полагаю, что теперь стало ясно в чём проблема и во втором задании.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Да, действительно, ошибка была как раз в том, что я перепутал div и mod :)